# How to determine regressive tax

Tags: taxation

I have a mock-up exam that my teacher gave me and one of the questions was the following:

> Given these four graphs, which one represents regressive tax?

I'm quite sure it's graph A, but I don't seem to be able to find a proper reason why. Any help and/or tips are welcome!

Thanks in advance

EDIT: As per request. How I interpret this: regressive means the higher the income, the lower the tax. Thus: tax drops with higher incomes. But I can't really determine to which graph this applies.

[image]

(T is tax, Y is income)

Comment: Perhaps you could add what you think "Regressive" means in your own words, and then try to come up what that means mathematically?

Comment: Is T a tax rate or taxes in units of Y?

Comment: @FooBar I edited my question ;)

Comment: @BKay Good question, I'm quite sure it's taxes in units of Y. I'm from Belgium but if I try and translate it's: "total indebted tax"

Comment: Don't you mean "*the higher the income, the lower the **marginal** tax*"?

Comment: @FooBar yes, that's what I meant. I have the feeling that I'm missing/overlooking something very easy/trivial ;)

Comment: As a first step, try drawing what the average and marginal tax rates look like. That might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct it is graph A. Regressive tax means that the lower income you have the higher %tax you have. If you imagine at the lowest level of income, you still have a flat tax(The intercept).

Since the slope is constant the %tax component is the same for all income levels.

Therefore this flat tax component is the part you need to look at. The flat tax represents a larger proportion for lower income earners. As a whole (%tax + Flat tax) the tax is then a higher % for lower income earners, hence regressive taxation.